# android setOnItemClickListener in dynamic Listview

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-listview

Hi everyone :) I create dynamically Listview. This listview changes items flexibility depending on the action of the user. **But my program has the click event of the first list, even if the list changes.** Do I need to register a new `setOnItemClickListener` when the list every change?

My code :

onCreate

```
final ArrayList<Item> items = setList("all"); //set list item dynamically

VenuesListAdapter adapter = new VenuesListAdapter(getActivity(), items);
mListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position > 1){
            Log.d(getTag(), ""+items.get(position).getText());
        }
    }
});
```

When change list (Usually when click a button)

```
ArrayList<Item> items = setList("barra"); //set list item dynamically
mListView.setAdapter(new VenuesListAdapter(getActivity(), items));
```

Add list item dynamically method

```
ArrayList<Item> setList(String type){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    switch (type){
         case "all":
            items.add(new VenuesListHeader("All"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Olympic stadium"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Sambodromo"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Maracana"));
            break;
        case "barra":
            items.add(new VenuesListHeader("Barra"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Olympic gold course"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Pontal"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Barra olympic park"));
            items.add(new VenuesListItem("Riocentro"));
            break;
            .
            .
            .
    }
    return items;
}
```

**Despite the call the setList("barra"), If click the first item in the list view, print 'all' not 'barra'**. Is there another way that register `setOnItemClickListener` whenever call `setAdapter()` ?

Comment: Is onItemClick event working for the first row of the ListView?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid `setOnItemClickListener` working  for created in the `onCreate`.. I will modify the question easy to understand. Wait a second :)

Comment: another way if you use custom adapter, set `setOnClickLisenter` before `getView` return view.

Comment: before you add it to the items array clear the items array and assign it and call notifyDatasetChanged() no need to reset the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the codes you provided, I don't see that you have multiple implementations of `OnItemClickListener`. Basically when you select an item in the list view, you just log its content. You don't have to create a new adapter every time you use `setList(String type)`. Just replace the list ArrayList items in your `setList(String type)` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so the changes are reflected by the list view.

Answer (score 0):

No. But I think you can simply make the action of item click listener depend on the content of your `Item`.

I think the solution would be straightforward but I am not sure I interepreted your question correctly. 
So you have two kinds of items and depending on the item type, log the content. I would first *add* the type in `Item`

```
class Item {
  ...
  public VenuesListItem venueItem;
  public VenuesListHeader venueHeader;
  public String type;     
}
```

And then do the plumbing in OnItemClickListener

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Item it = items.get(position);
   if (it.type.equals("all")){
      ...
   }else if (it.type.equals("barra"){
      ...
   }
}
});
```

And you shouldn't initialize the List in the adapter all the time. What you should do is

```
void setList(String type){

  // Use the original items reference
  items.clear();

  switch (type){
     case "all":
        items.add(new VenuesListHeader("All"));
        ...
        break;
    case "barra":
        items.add(new VenuesListHeader("Barra"));
        ... 
        break;

  }
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your above code I have noticed 2 things-

1. whenever you are adding new items, call items.clear() to remove old values.
2. After adding new items to the ArrayList items rather calling

   ArrayList items = setList("barra"); //set list item dynamically
   mListView.setAdapter(new VenuesListAdapter(getActivity(), items));

call

```
ArrayList<Item> items = setList("barra"); //set list item dynamically
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

as adapter is already added to the listview calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will update the items of the list.